# Having trouble finding openpyxl equivalent of xlrd objects

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, openpyxl, xlrd

I wrote my code using `xlrd` package for extracting specific information from excel file with multiple sheets. I partial match a string and get the value in the next column, and sometimes, I get the values in the next row for the same column depending on the requirement.

The below code is a part of my code using `xlrd` which works fine to pick value in the next column:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('sample_data.xlsx')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
        row = sheet.row(rowidx)
        row_val = sheet.row_values(rowidx)

        for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell.value == "Student number":
                sheet_name.append(sheet.name)
                print("Sheet Name =", sheet.name)
                customer_num.append(sheet.cell(rowidx,colidx+1).value)
                print(cell.value + "=" , sheet.cell(rowidx,colidx+1).value)
```

But I now need to use `openpyxl` instead of `xlrd` to achieve this. It's a technical requirement. And I'm unable to find proper counterparts from the `openpyxl` package. I'm pretty new to Python too.

It would be very helpful and time saving if someone who has good knowledge of both `xlrd` and `openpyxl` can help me on how to replicate my above code using `openpyxl`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ws in wb:
   for row in ws:
      for cell in row:
         if cell.value == "Student number":
             print(sheet.title)
             print("{0} = {1}".format(cell.value, cell.offset(column=1).value))
```

Comment: Thanks, Charlie. This works perfectly for value in the next cell. Is there also a way to access the value in the next row for the matched cell? Something like `sheet.cell(rowidx+1,colidx).value` from `xlrd`?

Comment: That's what `cell.offset()` does.

Comment: How can I loop through current column where a string match was found instead of hardcoding the column in the for loop?:
 `for cell in ws['D']:
     if (cell.value is not None):
      print(cell.value)`